# Stop at nth element?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Not sure how to add a condition to make result output stops at third last words.

Currently working on printing out specific words within the texts:

```
My feet they are sore and my limbs they are weary
Long is the way and the mountains are wild
```

I managed to print out the output of:

```
they sore my they weary
the and mountains wild
```

But what i am trying to print out is:

```
they sore my they
the and mountains
```

Which stops at the third last of the sentences

The code:

```
for line in open("testing.txt"):
  low = line.lower()
  words = low.split()
  n = 2
  print(" ".join(words[n::n]))
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use the word list from `n` to `-2` (to stop at 3rd last word) instead of the whole list

```
print(" ".join(words[n:-2:n]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in open("testing.txt") 
    low = line.lower()
    words = low.split()
    words = words[0:-2]
    n = 2
    print(" ".join(words[n::n]))
```